# Jenkins+Yandex-tank+Jmeter and hanged jobs

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, yandex, yandex-tank

I am using CI Jenkins for automation of load-testing with yandex-tank + jmeter. I am using distributed testing and starting summary 10k threads. So, I have a problem when the test should be finished but it`s not happening because (I think so) some threads on remote machines are stuck. 
Also, I tried to use these settings in jmeter.properties file:

```
jmeterengine.threadstop.wait=1000
jmeterengine.remote.system.exit=true
jmeterengine.stopfail.system.exit=true
jmeterengine.force.system.exit=true
jmeter.exit.check.pause=1000
```

But it does not help. Are there some another for force stopping of jmeter without killing java process?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem, I've tried the Jenkins option:

```
Abort the build if it's stuck, Strategy: Absolut, 120 minutes
```

It didn't help for me, but it would worth a try.